# Accessing layer's input/output using Tensorflow 2.0 Model Sub-classing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Working on a university exercise, I used the model sub-classing API of TF2.0. Here's my code (it's the Alexnet architecture, if you wonder...):

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        # OPS
        self.relu = Activation('relu', name='ReLU')
        self.maxpool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', name='MaxPool')
        self.softmax = Activation('softmax', name='Softmax')

        # Conv layers
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), padding='same',
                            name='conv1')
        self.conv2a = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv2a')
        self.conv2b = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv2b')
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv3')
        self.conv4a = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv4a')
        self.conv4b = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv4b')
        self.conv5a = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv5a')
        self.conv5b = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv5b')

        # Fully-connected layers

        self.flatten = Flatten()

        self.dense1 = Dense(4096, input_shape=(100,), name='FC_4096_1')
        self.dense2 = Dense(4096, name='FC_4096_2')
        self.dense3 = Dense(1000, name='FC_1000')

        # Network definition

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(x, depth_radius=2, alpha=2e-05, beta=0.75, bias=1.0)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = tf.concat((self.conv2a(x[:, :, :, :48]), self.conv2b(x[:, :, :, 48:])), 3)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(x, depth_radius=2, alpha=2e-05, beta=0.75, bias=1.0)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = tf.concat((self.conv4a(x[:, :, :, :192]), self.conv4b(x[:, :, :, 192:])), 3)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = tf.concat((self.conv5a(x[:, :, :, :192]), self.conv5b(x[:, :, :, 192:])), 3)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.flatten(x)

        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        return self.softmax(x)
```

My goal is to access an arbitrary layer's output (in order to maximize a specific neuron's activation, if you have to know exactly :) ). The problem is that trying to access any layer's output, I get an attribute error. For example:

```
model = MyModel()
print(model.get_layer('conv1').output)
# => AttributeError: Layer conv1 has no inbound nodes.
```

I found some questions with this error here in SO, and all of them claim that I have to define the input shape in the first layer, but as you can see - it's already done (see the definition of `self.conv1` in the `__init__` function)!

I did find that if I define a `keras.layers.Input` object, I do manage to get the output of `conv1`, but trying to access deeper layers fails, for example:

```
model = MyModel()
I = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
model(I)
print(model.get_layer('conv1').output)
# prints Tensor("my_model/conv1/Identity:0", shape=(None, 56, 56, 96), dtype=float32)
print(model.get_layer('FC_1000').output)
# => AttributeError: Layer FC_1000 has no inbound nodes.
```

I googled every exception that I got on the way, but found no answer. How can I access any layer's input/output (or input/output _shape attributes, by the way) in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sub-classed model there is no graph of layers, it's just a piece of code (models `call` function). Layer connections are not defined while creating instance of Model class. Hence we need to build model first by calling `call` method.

Try this:

```
model = MyModel()
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
model.call(inputs)
# instead of model(I) in your code.
```

After doing this model graph is created.

```
for i in model.layers:
  print(i.output)
# output
# Tensor("ReLU_7/Relu:0", shape=(?, 56, 56, 96), dtype=float32)
# Tensor("MaxPool_3/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 27, 27, 96), dtype=float32)
# Tensor("Softmax_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working! 2 questions though: 1. I still don't understand why calling `model(I)` doesn't work - what's different when we do this (calling without the explicit `call` function). 2. Some of the layers are being reused (e.g, the ReLU layer) - is there a way to access the different outputs of each activation of these layers (I believe that I can use a naive solution of simply duplicating these layers, but I wonder if there's a more efficient solution).

Comment: @noamgot Q1: From what I understood from ```tf.keras.models.Model``` github repo, ```call``` method calls parent method from Network class which builds network graph while calling sub-classed model object only passes input to call method of custom (MyModel). Though I am not sure! Q2. As you said, for sub-classed model only way is to duplicating these layers. Although if you find any work-around please share!

Comment: Even if I use the method `call`, I receive the following error `*** AttributeError: Layer dense_12 has no inbound nodes.` whenever I use model subclassing. Is there a workaround for that?